# Loading jsTree v3 using ajax when clicking +

Tags: jstree

I have the ajax round-trip working fine with the code below. I'd like to populate a node's children when that node is clicked.

```
                      "core" : {                                                       
                      'data' : {                              
                          'url' : function(node) {
                              return "source.php";                                
                          },
                          'dataType': 'JSON',
                          'data' : function (node) {
                              return {'parentkey' : node.id, 'isajax' : '1'};
                          },
```

What I can't get is a plus(+) sign to display next to my newly added nodes. I have seen this post

http://www.miketyka.com/2012/10/lazy-loading-with-jstree-and-ajax/

but that seems to be for an old grid version. I have also read that I should set "children:true" in my json for the parent node, but that just crashes my tree. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure what was crashing the grid, it must have been some problem with my JSON but this works when returned from server php code ie. a + sign is displayed next to empty parent node and when it is clicked it fires the next ajax request.

```
$dataArray = array("id" => "id1", "parent" => "#", "text" => "Simple root node", "children" => true);
echo json_encode($dataArray);
```